# Azure function storage file isn't deleted with function

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

When I create new Azure function, the specified storage account also create logs and files like host locks. For consumption, plan storage uses File Share to store whole function app by default.

When I want to delete my azure function, nothing is deleted in the storage account.

Storage account after deleted:
[image]

1. Is that correct for consumption plan?
2. Should I delete it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On either a Consumption plan or an App Service plan, a function app requires a general Azure Storage account, which supports Azure Blob, Queue, Files, and Table storage. This is because Functions relies on Azure Storage for operations such as managing triggers and logging function executions, but some storage accounts do not support queues and tables.

They are part of a resource group, if you don't delete the whole resource group you have to delete each item seperately.

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: Will it affect on payment or should we skip it?

Comment: If you are not using the resource I advice you delete it to save costs.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/page-blobs/

Comment: Can we delete these files automatically when deleting function?

Comment: you should delete the resource group in that case

Comment: I use a single storage account for all functions, this leaves me with tons of folders for historical already deleted function. Is there a way to check weather a folder is still in use by a function?

Comment: Check you storage credentials in app settings or in your code if it is hard coded.

Comment: One storage for all function is a very bad practice, storage is not expensive in blob though

Comment: please mark the question as answered if you think it solved the issue